# how to read data from an excel worksheet dynamically using VBA 2003

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am new to vba programming hence I need your expert help in trying to be able to able to read all values from the following excel sheet into a ADODB recordset object using VBA 2003

[image]
The recordset will be populated as follows

```
   'Create new recordset with the following fields
        Dim rsData as new ADODB.Recordset
        rsData.Fields.Append "Month", adVarChar, 20
        rsData.Fields.Append "Product", adVarChar, 20
        rsData.Fields.Append "Type", adVarChar, 50
        rsData.Fields.Append "Value", adVarChar, 50
        rsData.Open


    'for each row in spreadsheet read the following info
       rsData.Addnew
            rsData.Fields("Month") = 'value from row 2 Jan followed by data below
            rsData.Fields("Product") = "Color" ' Value from B5
            rsData.Fields("Type") = "MK1" ' value from C5
            rsData.Fields("Value") = "111=" ' value from D6

'Now move to next set of values for Feb

    rsData.Addnew
            rsData.Fields("Month") = 'value from row 2 FEB
            rsData.Fields("Product") = "Shade" ' Value from F5
            rsData.Fields("Type") = "AB2" ' value from G5
            rsData.Fields("Value") = "345=ABX" ' value from H5

    'Now move to next set of values for Mar
    rsData.Addnew
            rsData.Fields("Month") = 'value from row 2 MAR
            rsData.Fields("Product") = "Color" ' Value from F5
            rsData.Fields("Type") = "3FG" ' value from G5
            rsData.Fields("Value") = "PLZ" ' value from H5

    'Now move to next row
 rsData.Addnew
            rsData.Fields("Month") = 'value from row 2 Jan
            rsData.Fields("Product") = "Color" ' Value from F5
            rsData.Fields("Type") = "MK2" ' value from C6
            rsData.Fields("Value") = "234=BZX" ' value from D6

...and so on
```

Please note, **the data may move around but the overall layout will remain unchanged.

As you can see from the following diagram. the order has changed: Jan , march, Feb**

[image]

Comment: You need to make your question clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't really VBA for Excel, the problem is that that's a garbage data source. If the blocks can move around and be in any order, you really have no easy way of telling where they'll be and how much data is in them. That being the case you'd be much better off asking the questions:

- Does the source data need to be in this format; and
- Is there a way that we can do it better?

("Better" = more structured, more predictable.)

Also you're thinking too much in terms of each row being a record. Each block is quite separate from the others and since each one has a unique "header record" (being the month) I'd be inclined to process each block in turn rather than trying to jump from one to the other as your sample code tries to do.

The following should give you enough of a grounding to be able to navigate your way through an Excel worksheet. It's just something that I whacked together quickly and have not bullet-proofed though I did test it with a mock-up of the sheet in your second illustration and it did work. It should be enough to help set you on the right course, but I again emphasise... what you have is not a true data source. It's a report that needs to be almost arbitrarily parsed. You need to see whether that can be addressed before you do anything.

```
Sub DemonstrateReadingFromExcel()

'Every cell in Excel is a range.
'A range can also be a collection of cells.
'Ranges have properties that you can query. More importantly
'you can redefine a range by offsetting it from
'your current range, which makes it easy to step through a block.
Dim rng_Month As Excel.Range
Dim rng_Data As Excel.Range

'Let's define some string variables that you can use to assign
'to your recordset's fields.
Dim s_Month As String
Dim s_Product As String
Dim s_Type As String
Dim s_Value As String

Dim l_RowCurrent As Long
Dim l_RowLastType As Long

Dim l_ColumnOfMonth As Long

'We have to start with the cell containing the month.
'Rather than reading row by row, you'd be better off
'reading a whole block at a time.

'Your big problem will be telling WHERE the cell containing
'that month is and for that reason I think you need to seriously
'look at WHY the data is in the format that it is and whether
'you can actually use a much more structured data source.

'For now though let's pretend that you have some magic way of knowing
'where the range is and assign it to a range variable.

'ActiveSheet is a reference to the active worksheet but just as you
'can use a range variable to store a reference to a range,
'you can use a worksheet variable to store a reference to a worksheet
'(even one which is not the active sheet) if you want to.
'I'm only using ActiveSheet for convenience.

'You need to use the Set statement because you're assigning an object.

Set rng_Month = ActiveSheet.Range("C2")

'Ranges have properties like their column number.
'We already know the column number for this range but let's
'assume that we don't in a more general solution.

l_ColumnOfMonth = rng_Month.Column

'Now let's check that the range is valid.
'Don't worry about what the number means,
'just look at the error description.
'If this is True then there must be something wrong with the range.

If l_ColumnOfMonth < 2 Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 20000, , "There are no columns to the left of the month. " _
     & "The range is invalid."
End If

'Now let's find out where the last Type entry occurs in the current
'block. We go up from the bottom of the column to do that.

'In this case we're passing the row and column to the Cells
'property. This defines a range for us representing the bottom
'of the Type column. Using End(xlUp) is the same as pressing the
'[End] key then the [Up arrow] key. It takes us to the last
'populated row, which we read the .Row property of.

l_RowLastType = ActiveSheet.Cells( _
 ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, l_ColumnOfMonth).End(xlUp).Row

'If this is the same as the Month's own row, there's no data
'in that block.

If l_RowLastType = rng_Month.Row Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 20000, , "There are no Type entries in this block. "
End If

'So we've checked that the range looks OK.
'Before we proceed, let's store the month for this block.
'We just get the Value property of the range.
s_Month = rng_Month.Value

'We know that the first product should be 3 rows down and
'one row to the left of the month, so let's just keep looping
'through and reading the values for each row in the block
'until we reach the end of it. We know the end because
'we have its row stored in the l_RowLastType variable.

Set rng_Data = rng_Month.Offset(3, -1)

'Let's get the name of the first product.
s_Product = rng_Data.Value

'If that's nothing, there's a problem.
If s_Product = "" Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 20000, , "No valid product in the expected location. "
End If

'Now let's loop through each row.
For l_RowCurrent = rng_Month.Row + 3 To l_RowLastType

    'Let's look at another way that we can get a reference to
    'a range; by using the Cells property of the sheet.
    'For that we specify the row number and column number.

    Set rng_Data = ActiveSheet.Cells(l_RowCurrent, rng_Month.Column - 1)

    'We know that there won't be a product on each row,
    'so if there isn't one we just use the previous one.
    'Otherwise we assign the new product.

    If rng_Data.Value <> "" Then
        s_Product = rng_Data.Value
    End If

    'Now let's get the type, which is offset 0 rows, 1 column
    'to the right of the product.
    s_Type = rng_Data.Offset(0, 1)

    'If that's a blank cell (like row 8 in your
    'second example we won't do anything else.
    'We only proceed if it's populated.

    If s_Type <> "" Then
        s_Value = rng_Data.Offset(0, 2)

        'Now at this point you have gathered all of your values
        'into variables, and can feed them to your recordset.
        'In this case though we'll just output
        'a messagebox.

        MsgBox "Row " & rng_Data.Row & " is for month " & s_Month _
         & ", product " & s_Product & ", Type " & s_Type _
         & ", Value " & s_Value

    End If

Next

ExitPoint:

On Error Resume Next
Set rng_Month = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description

Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```